# Retrieve highest point of a shape

Tags: java, swing, shapes

I have floating islands in my game and have implemented gravity. These islands are in funny shapes, so I was wondering how I could make my player character go on the islands without phasing through (as shown below)
[image: movement]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Area;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main().show());
    }
    
    int x = 0;
    int y = 50;
    
    Area area = new Area();
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        protected void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g1) {
            super.paintComponent(g1);
            
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1;
            
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fill(area);
            
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
        }
    };
    
    boolean left;
    boolean right;
    
    public Main() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.add(panel);
        
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        
        // GENERATING TERRAIN
        int offset = 200;
        boolean reachedPeak = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            if(!reachedPeak) {
                offset--;
                if(offset < 100)
                    reachedPeak = true;
                
                area.add(new Area(new Rectangle(i, offset, 1, 1000)));
            }
            if(reachedPeak) {
                offset++;
                if(offset > 200)
                    reachedPeak = false;
                area.add(new Area(new Rectangle(i, offset, 1, 1000)));
            }
        }
        
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                    left = true;
                
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                    right = true;
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                    left = false;
                
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                    right = false;
            }
        });
        
        new Timer(5, e -> update()).start();
    }
    
    private void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
     
    private void update() {
        if(left)
            x -= 5;
        
        if(right)
            x += 5;
        
        panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Here is an MRE. The player goes through the terrain, instead I want him to follow along with the terrain. Please ignore terrain generation, I am converting a transparent image into a shape in my actual program, so saving the `y` during terrain generation doesn't help me.

Comment: Much would depend on information that has not been presented in your question yet, including GUI libraries used and code not shown. Please consider giving the question and [edit] and asking a more complete question, one whose information and answers could be helpful for all, one that is possible for us to answer without guessing at unknowns.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels there is not a lot of code I could provide, please specifying exactly what you need, and I will add it to the question / give it to you.

Comment: I have no idea what you have and so I can't "specify what I need" other than best would be to create and provide a [mre] program (please read the link).  Otherwise, all I can say is that it is your question, and so you'll want to provide enough information so that we can fully understand what is going on. We're all volunteers, and so the weight of responsibility in this endeavor is on you.

Comment: Your question looks to be about a Swing GUI with animation (consider adding those tags if appropriate), and in particular, about collision detection between shapes. If so, then some of [these potentially relevant Google search hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+swing+shape+collision+detection) may prove useful.

Comment: Instead of finding the highest point, it looks to me as if you want to almost trace the contours of the tops of the green islands. If you have a specific pixel location at the bottom of your player, conceivably, you could check the adjacent pixels. If you are moving left to right, check the pixels to the upper right, center right, lower right, and bottom. The player moves right and up, straight right, or right and down.